# Notify before closing the Android App on user request

Tags: android, performance, android-activity

My Requirement is :

```
              Once my android app is opened, then I will activate bluetooth. On closure of my android app I want to disable bluetooth.
```

Question is:
                 how can I know that user requested to close the app programatically in android.?

Answer (score 0):

Read about the Android activity lifecycle http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

According to your requirement, it seems that you would want to disable bluetooth inside `onDestroy` method.

Comment: onDestroy will be called only when Activity is closed/destroyed. But my requirement is when app is closed (user closes the app from foreground process), I want to call method something like onDestroy.